# What happens to a captured noble?

Tags: warfare, politics

I am currently at a crossroad there could be many option for him/her and I am trying to build the conclusion of a legend of an ancient war that took place in a city long forgotten. Simply put "What do I do with the vanquished?"

Comment: If you are asking "how could he be leveraged", we would need a lot more context to answer that usefully.

Comment: Hello Julio.  Welcome to world building.  Unfortunately as written this question is off topic for the site as it ventures into the realm of idea generation.

Comment: [Backstab them and take their stuff](http://www.worldofmunchkin.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Generally there are several options that have traditionally been used.

1. Ransom them back for money (they can even pay their own ransom).
2. When conquered. Turn them into slaves
3. When a rebellion, either success or fail the losers often are executed.
4. Make the useful ones vassals to help run the empire.

Comment: But how could I guarantee that this newly acquired vassal does not betray me?

Comment: @Juliotheunpublished There are never any guarantees, but 'keeping' his children safe and teaching them the ways of the new empire in the capitol can go a long way.

Comment: @Juliotheunpublished - How does any lord guarantee that his vassals will not betray him?

Comment: Historically this is pretty much what happened, historically. There's never any way to guarantee that you won't be betrayed, but by raising and indoctrinating the nobility's children you seed the next generation with more and more leaders who will be on "your side". The ones who don't buy into your ideology, plot against you, etc you simply execute - very publicly.

Answer (score 1):

Kill them and take their lands...it's far more pain to have them left alive.   Fuedal lords come with claims to land and allowing them to live is allowing the claim to continue.  It might not be an immediate claim, but some where down the line they could try to reclaim their land (either through diplomacy, but can be military).  Soldiers and people that followed the lord are fine being left alive, but the lord himself is best deposed and disposed.

Answer (score 0):

1) This one is the easiest. Just kill him. I don't think I really need to go into detail with this.

2) Shame him. Depending on your world's social structure, honor could be used as a powerful weapon.

3) Make him work. This one is rather simple. Why have a captive that just sits there and eats your food? Get some usefulness out of him!

4) Gladiators. Only use this one if you don't necessarily need your captive to survive. The mortality rate is a bit high, but the entertainment value tends to boost patriotism for your cause/country.

These are just a few i came up with off the top of my head. I my add some more later.

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious two would be to either make an example of him, or to co-opt him.

The example depends on how ruthless you want your legend to be.  A simple execution probably won't get much.  Torture followed by execution will get more attention, but might be counter-productive if other people think that they might get the same treatment by surrendering.  And if you want to be really extreme, you can run the gauntlet of torture and killing on his entire family, publicly.

Co-opting him is tricky, because you'll want safeguards to prevent betrayal.  The preventative steps you want to take depend on the reason for trying to turn him.

1. If you want to turn him because he's competent, you should give him a different position.  So maybe strip him of his lands, but grant him a military or administrative position elsewhere, surrounded by people you know to be loyal.  Keep his family under guard.  Promise him different, equivalent lands at the end of his service - so he won't get his lands back, but eventually he'll get something similar elsewhere.  That gives him a lot of motivation as long as he believes you.  If his behavior is good and you believe he's trustworthy, remove the guards on the family and increase his rewards and responsibilities accordingly.
2. If he's not competent, you might still want to turn him in order to incentivize others.  In this case you should make him a visible figurehead, with a competent underling loyal to you who will do most of the real work.  You should otherwise follow similar precautions - surround him with people loyal to you, and keep his family and/or friends as lightly veiled hostages.